# how can i create the menu that will open only the article in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have created the articles and menu items that links to that articles. This all works.

But now what I want is, when I click on the menu, it should open up only article (without any  template feature, no header , no footer and not even the menu).I am opening the article in a new window. From googling what I found is if I add &tmpl=component to the url it will just load the component, and that will show just the article. But I am not sure how to add this parameter from admin screen to the menu items. The link which is showed in admin screen is not editable!!!. Or should I have to develop a custom menu module to achieve this!!!?

Thanks for help.
Tanmay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new menu item - External Link and then paste the full URL into the box.

http://www.jeepstone.co.uk/2009/03/06/open-content-in-a-modal-pop-up-in-joomla/

Comment: thanks for your answer. That works for me. I had one more question if you can give me some suggestion. As I am opening the article in a new window with only component, how can I load the css specific for that article. With your trick no css is applied!! 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Within /templates/yourtemplate/component.php is the file that gets loaded so you can modify this as required.